# Tricky puzzle, Half way there! Reading capital letters

Tags: python

To start off, this is my code:

```
s = raw_input("code: ")
s1 = " ".join(s.split()[::-1])
lists = s1.split()
for i in lists:
    if i.istitle() == True:
        print i
```

What it currently does is it reverses a string, and prints a word if it starts with a capital letter. However the problem is, if a word is like "CApital", it does not print it.

Let me show some examples of how how I would like the program to work:

1. Read the words in reverse order
2. Only pay attention to the words in the message that start with
   an uppercase letter

   If this is inputed: BaSe fOO ThE AttAcK
   Then it should return: attack the base

Another example:

```
code: soMe SuPPLies liKE Ice-cREAm aRe iMPORtant oNly tO THeir cReaTORS. tO DestroY thEm iS pOInTLess.
says: destroy their ice-cream supplies
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: why do you convert it back to a string and then immediately turn it back into a list?

Comment: you say "if a word is like "CApital", it does not print it." ... but then you print `THeir`

Comment: @JoranBeasley: that's in the original string. Note that `THeir` does not appear in the output, which is `destroy their ice-cream supplies` (I agree it's not explained too clearly)

Comment: yeah i know ... wants them lower but the match definition does not match the input/output he showed...

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `istitle`

```
if word[0].isupper():
    # do stuff
```

Answer (score 1):

`.istitle()` is only true if only the first letter of each word is capitalized:

```
print 'MArk'.istitle()
print 'Mark'.istitle()  # True
print 'MARK'.istitle()
print 'marK'.istitle()
print 'Spam SPAM'.istitle()
print 'SPam Spam'.istitle()
print 'Spam Spam'.istitle() # True
```

So just test the first letter:

```
strings = [
    'BaSe fOO ThE AttAcK',
    'soMe SuPPLies liKE Ice-cREAm aRe iMPORtant oNly tO THeir cReaTORS. tO DestroY thEm iS pOInTLess']
for s in strings:
    print ' '.join(
        i for i in reversed(s.split()) if i[0].isupper()
        ).lower()
```

Output:

```
attack the base
destroy their ice-cream supplies
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in lists:
    if i[0].isupper() and  i[1].islower():
        print i
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
s1 = s.split()[::-1]
for word in s1:
    if word[0].istitle() is True:
        out_list.append(word.lower())
print " ".join(out_list)
```

or in a more complicated but shorter version

```
print " ".join(map(str.lower, filter(lambda x:x[0].istitle(), s.split()[::-1])))
```

Comment: I dont think this is what he wants... its matching the desired pattern not forcing it...

Comment: It matches all his test cases. By the way, I did understand what you mean by forcing it

Comment: From my understanding what he wanted was to type the lower case of( the reversed string containing (characters with first letter upper case)). Do correct me if I am wrong